# git stash uncommited files disappeared

Tags: git, git-stash

I had a few stashes of uncommitted files `git stash -u`. I was able to apply them in the past and get the uncommitted files. But now after the last stash none of the stashes in my `git stash list` are bringing back the uncommitted files. What could have happened? Are the stashes lost forever?

Comment: If you've run `git stash pop` or `git stash drop` on the stash made with `-u`, those commits are "lost". They're *probably* not yet *gone* and `git fsck` should be able to find them as a "dangling commit". Look for a dangling commit that has three parents with the third parent being a zero-parent (root) commit; that's a stash made with `git stash -u` and the untracked files are in the third parent.

Comment: If `git gc` got around to running and *did* clean out those commits for real, then the files are gone forever as far as Git is concerned; you'd need a true backup (such as those made by macOS Time Machine) to get the files back.

Comment: I didn't run `git stash pop` or `drop`. I ran `git stash apply <number>`.  This is why the stashes are still there- To be more clear, the stashes are there in the git `git stash list`. But when I apply them they're not applying anything. I had applied some of them before no problem. But now nothing happens. But I do see dangling blobs and one dangling commit when I run `git fsck`.

Comment: Ah, good - then you *do* still have the stash and it's easy to find its third commit. Run `git show stash^3` to see it (assuming it's the topmost, or `stash@{0}`, stash; if not, use the `stash@{number}` syntax and add the `^3`). Getting the files *back* is a little trickier, and it's a bug that Git didn't get them back for you, but others have reported success using `git cherry-pick stash^3` (which stages the old untracked files and you then have to unstage them all with `git reset` or `git rm --cached`).

Comment: Thank you this was very interesting but I'm so silly, I accidentally committed a bunch of changes and pushed them and that's where those "untracked" changes went.  X( Appreciate the help! Your advice helped me realize the mistake when I saw some of the stashes third commits were full of code I had.